# T-sql using AVG in Group By with conditional/where result

Tags: sql-server, average

**T-SQL Query:**

```
  SELECT

    RESULT.Year AS 'Year',
    RESULT.Month AS 'Month',
    RESULT.EmployeeNumber,
    RESULT.StartedWorking,
    RESULT.SeperatedWorking,
    (AVG(RESULT.SeperatedWorking / RESULT.EmployeeNumber * 100)) AS ConversionRate

    FROM (

                    SELECT  
                        YEAR(CreatedAt) AS 'Year', 
                        12 AS 'Month',
                        COUNT(*) AS 'EmployeeNumber',
                        COUNT(EmploymentStartDate) AS 'StartedWorking',
                        COUNT(EmploymentEndDate) AS 'SeperatedWorking'

                    FROM Employees 

                    WHERE IsDeleted = 0

                    GROUP BY 
                    YEAR(CreatedAt)

    ) AS RESULT
```

**Question:**

I am trying to use below formula for **ConversionRate column**

```
COUNT(EmploymentEndDate) / COUNT(EmploymentStartDate) * 100
```

I am trying below query in select In order to get result as below

```
(AVG(RESULT.SeperatedWorking / RESULT.EmployeeNumber * 100)) AS ConversionRate
```

This query displays below error AS

```
"Column 'RESULT.Year' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
"
```

How can i get correct result by using AVG for "ConversionRate" column ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also have to add `group by` in your outer query. Like:

```
SELECT

    RESULT.Year AS 'Year',
    RESULT.Month AS 'Month',
    RESULT.EmployeeNumber,
    RESULT.StartedWorking,
    RESULT.SeperatedWorking,
    (AVG(RESULT.SeperatedWorking / RESULT.EmployeeNumber * 100)) AS ConversionRate

    FROM (

                    SELECT  
                        YEAR(CreatedAt) AS 'Year', 
                        12 AS 'Month',
                        COUNT(*) AS 'EmployeeNumber',
                        COUNT(EmploymentStartDate) AS 'StartedWorking',
                        COUNT(EmploymentEndDate) AS 'SeperatedWorking'

                    FROM Employees 

                    WHERE IsDeleted = 0

                    GROUP BY 
                    YEAR(CreatedAt)

    ) AS RESULT

    GROUP BY
        RESULT.Year,
        RESULT.Month ,
        RESULT.EmployeeNumber,
        RESULT.StartedWorking,
        RESULT.SeperatedWorking
```

Answer (score 2):

As you use aggregate function in select list, you have to use GROUP BY in your outer query.